# Adding column to base SQL select statement

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Apologizes if this has been asked before but I was not sure even how to search for this.

I am using VB for code behind & want I am trying to find out is this;

I have a defined `SqlCommand`:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select [Field1], [Field2], [Field3] From [Table] Where [FieldX] = @parameter ")
```

How can I add another field using code with out changing the base `SqlCommand`?

So the temp `SqlCommand` would look like the following:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select [Field1], [Field2], [Field3] [Field4 Added Dynamically] From [Table] Where [FieldX] = @parameter ")
```

If I have confused anyone or everyone please let me know and I will do my best to try an explain clearer.

MC

Comment: you can edit the commandtext property

Comment: You mean the 4th column you'll need is defined in runtime?
In this case, you can have a variable `Field4`, and assign the column name to it. In your SQL command, just concatenate this variable accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Dim DynamicField = "FieldToAdd"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select [Field1], [Field2], [Field3], " + DynamicField + " From [Table] Where [FieldX] = @parameter ")
```

I dont remember the exact VB syntax but you can use replace:

```
Dim DynamicField = "FieldToAdd"
Dim Sql = "Select [Field1], [Field2], [Field3], ##DynamicField## From [Table] Where [FieldX] = @parameter "
Sql = Sql.Replace("##DynamicField##", DynamicField)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql)
```

Comment: OMG!! Sweet thats exactly what i am looking for!! Thanks!!

Comment: Off the wall Question: If I have the SqlCommand saved as string could you dynamically add a field to the string somehow. I only ask this because i can already hear my boss asking this...